# Is there a way to stick an HTML element to the bottom of the browser window?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble trying to stick a part of my HTML site to the bottom of the browser window.

Is there any fix while keeping the class as the one I am already using?

My code is below:

````
    <href style="width: 100%">
    <input type="button" value="OK">```



```<div class="after footer_side1_wrapper">                     
                <div>© 2022 website</div> 
            </div>```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `fixed` positioning if you are trying to make sure it stays at the bottom

```
<style>
.footer_side1_wrapper{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```css
      
.footer_side1_wrapper {
      position: sticky;
      bottom:0;
      left:0;
      right:0
      }
```